# Collapse groups

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Helo,

i have a table with groupsand i want to know how i can collapse categories in my table

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qD3DF5kInGXlsFPuGKVt)

***My HTML:***

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <tr>
        <td style=" background-color: #006DCC;color: white;" colspan="2">{{group.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members">
        <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ member.age }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wire in a variable to toggle it with ng-hide:

```
<tr>
    <td style=" background-color: #006DCC;color: white;" colspan="2" data-ng-click="hideGroup = !hideGroup">{{group.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="member in group.members" data-ng-hide="hideGroup">
    <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ member.age }}</td>
</tr>
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ABJ9It8qSqkPGzpYNyMp?p=preview